# Is it possible to make floated DIVs not to break onto newline when they don't fit the container?

Tags: html, css

Here's example HTML code:

```
<div id="container" style="">
 <div id="left" style="float: left; width: 200px;">...</div>
 <div id="right" style="float: right; width: 100px;">...</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to make `#right` not to jump on new line (below `#left`) if `#container` is resized to less than 300px?

Comment: Hm... you can change right div properties with media queries, if 'container' will have 100% width? but that doesn't have too much sense, imho....

Comment: What would you expect to happen? Should the container div stop shrinking? If so, set a minimum width: `min-width: 300px;`, but note that this adds scrolling.

Comment: This has been asked thousands of times.. Please use the search box.. About the question: `float` behaviour is to break line. You need another thing, such as `display: inline-block` combined with `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: @Eraph good question - thxvm. i would like to start resizing `#left` smaller so it fits and doesnt break.

Comment: Thanks all for comments - I upvoted all comments!

Comment: @JoaquínO Thanks Joaquin O! My situation was a bit different than others because of 200px and 100px size. Sorry if repeat question!

Answer (score 1):

Answer found with a short google search...

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `float`and give the container `white-space: nowrap`.

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#container > div {
    display: inline-block;
    height:120px;
    background: red;
}
```

Here an example: http://jsfiddle.net/wwwth4wx/

Comment: Thanks let me try this!!

Answer (score 0):

**If you really want to keep floats**, and keep both divs visible, media queries could help.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
 #right {

     width:35%!important;
   }
    #left {
      width:65%!important;

   }
}
```

Resize window in fiddle to see:

http://jsfiddle.net/aLcrgn72/

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain `!important` pieces?

Comment: !important is there just because of your inline styling precedence... if css is in css file, you don't need this - this is for demo purposes, i didn't changed your html :) @Down Voter - care to explain? :) If container = screen size -> (mobile view, probably) this is valid solution, i would say....

Comment: perhaps because the `media queries` you used is for the `screen` width of     `300px` and not the width of the `container`? Because I think the `screen` width will be greater than the `container` width.

Comment: Perhaps. However, i've mentioned in comment : 'if 'container' will have 100% width?' However, in that case: if just one particular div resizing is in question - inline-block isn't solution, too, right?